# Explain convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

If I know that series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent, then which of the following (and why) are also covergent?

1) $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{2n}$

2) $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2$

3) $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n a_n$

4) $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$

Comment: Hello. What are your guesses concerning the different propositions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. Consider the convergent series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ with $a_n=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$. Which of the series 1), 2) 3) and 4) are also convergent?

Comment: I think that:
1) could convergent or divergent
2) will be convergent 
3) will be convergent 
4) could convergent or divergent

Comment: This is not correct. Please consider just  the case $a_n=\dfrac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$. Which of the series 1), 2) 3) and 4) are also convergent?

Comment: 1) divergent, 2) divergent, 3) divergent, 4) divergent

Comment: @Snochacz Yes, now you are correct.